# HTC Preformance Issue with CodeNameOne App?

Tags: java, android, mobile, cross-platform, codenameone

I have created an app using codenameone , and while I am testing on various devices [ all good on different types , tried on Apple , Android ] ,
I noticed an issue on HTC devices , there are some unexcpected slowness while browsing the screens or moving through screens

Can you advice regarding some build parameters that would fix this issue , or any kind of method to figure out the delay source ??

Comment: have you tried using the performance manager and the htc skin in the simulator?

Comment: yes I tried , and no problem it is ok , without any slowness

Comment: have you splited creation and usage of your Forms and Dialogs?

Comment: it is already built in codenameone , what I do is give the form to showForm method and it will take care of the rest

Comment: Which specific HTC devices?  Some android manufacturers employ "throttlers" to slow down the processor to prevent them from heating up.  If I know the model number, I can research it further to see if this is one of those cases, and check if there is anything that can be done about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I am doing is splitting the creation and the usage of Dialogs and Forms. In case you are not using the GUIBuilder (no matter if new or old), then you can try this, too. It helped me with performance issues a lot, here is an example:

First, there will be a LoginForm:

```
class Login extends Form {
   MainForm f; //do not initiate

   public Login () {
     this.setLayout (BoxLayout.y());
     this.add(new Label("username:").add(new TextField("","username"));
     this.add(new Label("pw:").add(new TextField("","password"));
     Button login = new Button ("Login");
     login.addActionListener(e -> {
        f.provideParameters(providedName,providedPw);
        f.show();
     }
     Display.getInstance().scheduleBackgroundTask(new Runnable {
       public void run() {
         //initiation in the background
         f = new MainForm ();
       }
     );
}
```

Then there is the main Form

```
class MainForm extends Form {

  private Label welcomeLbl;

  public MainForm () {
    //here you dont have the username
    //but running it in the background creates all the components, so...
    welcomeLbl = new Label();
  }

  public void provideParameters (String name, String pw) {
    //...they are ready to use here!
    this.welcomeLbl.setText("Welcome " + name);
  }
}
```

This way I experienced a huge perfomance increase, as the building of complex objects was outsourced to the background rather than front.

*Note* This is just an example. The more complex your objects get, the higher the performance increase will be.

*Note2* This code is untested. It is just for clarification purpose

Comment: but using that I will lose the facilities that the GUI provides , Is there any kind of parameters that could help increase the performance ??

Comment: Have a look at this section: https://www.codenameone.com/manual/performance-debugging.html
maybe unused images

Comment: You shouldn't be creating MainForm() inside scheduleBackgroundTask() because that is not on the EDT.   Use callSerially() instead to ensure that it runs on the EDT.

Comment: this was a sample code to clarify a point anyway , still trying to find a best set of build parameters for codenameone to improve performance